# AXIOS GET request loop in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I have been meddling with axios in my react project (I am a beginner)

unfortunately my API request seems to loop.. I have read many other posts but I couldn't come up with a solution as to why this is happening, I have read about e.preventDefault() but I haven't managed to make it work

```
  const [state, set_state] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetch() {
      const res = await axios.get(`${genUrl()}`);
      set_state(res.data);
    }
    fetch();
  },[state.results]);
  const fetchedData = state.results;
```

I understand that genUrl runs forever, but I would like it to run only when the getLimitsFromGen changes (which is on route change)

```
 const genUrl = () => {
    const [l, o] = getLimitsFromGen(validGeneration);
    return `${API}?limit=${l}&offset=${o}`;
  };
```

Said that I don't really know what I am doing so I could be wrong completely

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why are you rewriting `fetch()`? You know that's a native Javascript function, that does not require Axios or any other library? `await fetch(url)`

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  It's difficult to understand what is happening without seeing your code for `getLimitsFromGen` and `validGeneration`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the dependency value in the `useEffect` hook is the reason for the update loop. Once you set the state, it would trigger an update which also triggers fetching and setting the state again. if `getLimitsFromGen(validGeneration)` is not an async function, you can set the return value of `getUrl` as your dependency. Read more about how to use useEffect [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). Also try renaming your fetch() function to something more specific, as already mention `fetch` is an inbuilt js function

```
 const [state, set_state] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await axios.get(`${genUrl()}`);
      set_state(res.data);
    }
    fetchData();
  },[genUrl()]);
  const fetchedData = state.results;
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your answer! That solved it! 

getLimitsFromGen is a simple switch statement

If I understood correctly you put genUrl as a dependency to make the useEffect run only when the genUrl function is triggered? (which in my case is when the route changes).

edit reading further downh the docs you linked I found the explanation. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @misto_robotto not necessary, ``useEffect`` triggers once when the component is mounted if you put an ``[]`` array as the dependency, however if you add any other value to the dependency array, it will trigger both once + any time that value changes. So in your case, it would trigger any time the return value of ``genUrl()`` changes.

Answer (score 1):

yeah it loops because you passed an argument to useEffect's dependency array so when that `state.result` changes useEffect calls fetch again

```
  const [state, set_state] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
   let mounted =true 

    async function fetch() {
      const res = await axios.get(`${genUrl()}`);
      if(mounted ){
           set_state(res.data);
      }
     
    }
    fetch();

    //this is for cleaning up use effect to prevent updating state when component is unmounted
    return ()=>mounted =false
  },[]);
  const fetchedData = state.results;
```